# the day after it rains, 2015 Honda Accord leaks water outside and inside the cab

Tags: honda, accord, leak, water-leak

We park our 2015 Honda Accord outside; our apartment has a parking lot with no covered spots. When it rains, water seems to be pooling up behind the dashboard somewhere. The next time we drive, when it's no longer raining, the collected water either sloshes out to the left onto the asphalt, or is sloshes out to the right inside the cab at the passenger's feet. On the right it appears to be coming from around the glove box area.

I opened the hood and looked for any blocked vents near the windshield. I cleaned out some leaves, but didn't find any water - and it didn't fix the issue.

The amount of water might be up to a quart, but it's hard to tell when we just hear it sloshing onto the asphalt on the driver's side. When it drips onto the passenger side mat in the car, under the glove box, it seems to be 1-2 cups of water or maybe more. Once the hidden water has drained out (within the first 30 seconds of driving), there is no more leaking / sloshing.

I'd love to know where to look under the hood and find the issue!

Comment: Roof / screen leak - amazing how far water can travel.

Comment: Any idea where it might be pooling up, that it sounds like it's right behind the dash?

Comment: Any place with a reverse curve...

Comment: Do you have a sunroof?

Comment: I don't have a sun roof. Good thought though.

Answer (score 2):

I am unfamiliar with this specific auto body.

Most newer cars, however, have an area just in front of the firewall where air, which has entered that space through slots in the rear edge of the hood, is then redirected into the cars interior hearing/air conditioning system.

This area typically has several drains in the bottom, so that rainwater entering the slots can run out onto the ground. The symptoms you report are what happens when the drains are plugged, and water enters and pools there: you hear it sloshing back and forth, and, eventually, it finds a way out...but not the way it should down the drain tubes.

Thus: find the drains, and clear them.

Comment: David is correct here. This is what I would recommend. Flash out old leaves and gunk out of all the rain water gutters in the car's cowl area and the over flow should stop.